# core.mjs:14631 NG0304: 'app-extraction' is not a known element:

Tags: angular, components

I generated with the ionic cli a component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-extraction',
  templateUrl: './extraction.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./extraction.component.scss'],
})
export class ExtractionComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {}

}
```

then I declared it in app.module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { ItemModule } from 'src/app/modules/item/item.module';
import { DynamicFormModule } from 'src/app/modules/dynamic-form/dynamic-form.module';
import { HelpersModule } from 'src/app/modules/helpers/helpers.module';
import { UserModule } from './modules/user/user.module';
import { SelectorItemsPage } from './modules/item/pages/selector-items/selector-items.page';
import { EditUserPage } from './modules/user/pages/edit-user/edit-user.page';
import { ProfilePage } from './modules/user/pages/profile/profile.page';
import { ExtractionComponent } from './components/extraction/extraction.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SelectorItemsPage,
    EditUserPage,
    ProfilePage,
    ExtractionComponent,
   ],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    DynamicFormModule,
    ItemModule,
    HelpersModule,
    UserModule,
    ],
  providers: [{ provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  exports:[
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

when I launch the development server I get this error:

```
NG0304: 'app-extraction' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-extraction' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-extraction' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

I  have read  many posts about this error, but have not been able to fix it

Comment: Where do you use `app-extraction` component?

Comment: inside  a page of my app the folder page create by ionic when it initializes a new project

Comment: Is this page component declared in `AppModule` as well?

Comment: Can you add a snippet of code where you are using app-extraction and some info about the module that uses this component?

Comment: thanks , the page where declared on its module, but not in app.module, I declared in app.module and removed I it in its module

Comment: Kamil Chlebev if you  answer I can award you but I do not know whether we ara still on time

Answer (score 0):

Few Troubleshooting steps that might help:

1. Check if you really have the correct folder path.
2. Try restarting ng serve command. Sometimes, module file is not updated.

Comment: the path is correct and already restarted ng serve

Answer (score 0):

check Ionic or any added third party libraries for compatible version step by step to find out when you get an error.